# Automorphism group of Cayley graph much larger than the subgroup preserving directedness

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group with generating set $S$ and $\Gamma$ the corresponding Cayley graph. Let $Aut(\Gamma)$ be the automorphism group of the corresponding undirected graph and $Aut^+(\Gamma)$ the subgroup preserving the directions and labellings of the Cayley graph.

It can happen that $Aut^+(\Gamma)$ is strictly smaller than the full automorphism group, for example with $G=S_3$ and $S$ consisting of $(12)$ and $(123)$.

I am looking for an example where the full automorphism group is much larger is the sense that the index $[Aut(\Gamma):Aut^+(\Gamma)]$ is infinite.

Comment: Free group......

Comment: @MoisheKohan That's what I thought too, but I couldn't find a way of proving it. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: If you are preserving labels and directions, then any element of $\mathrm{Aut}^+(\Gamma)$ is surely determined by what happens to the origin in $\Gamma$. So the $\mathrm{Aut}^*(\Gamma)$ is finite. For $\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)$, you can fix every vertex, pick a subset of the vertices, and exchange the branches labeled $x$ and $y$, working through vertices ordered in lexicographic order $x\lt x^{-1}\lt y\lt  y^{-1}$ to determine how the set gives an automorphism. Looks to me like you have uncountably many such automorphisms.

Comment: One group is countable, the other has cardinality of continuum (a pleasant exercise).

Comment: Of course, you should consider the case of of a free group of finite (or countable) rank $>1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I can see that $Aut^+(\Gamma)$ is countable. I can also see that pemuting the three branches around any vertex gives an automorphism but that seems to only give countably many as well. Can you explain how the automorphisms you described look like in more detail?

Comment: @mathemagician99: You permute around multiple vertices; pick any subset of the vertices, and permute on *each* of the vertices in the subset. You get one automorphism for each subset of vertices, and that's $2^{\aleph_0}$ automorphisms.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Got it, thanks.